# Multiple SSH sessions in a single command

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, shell, mysql

I'm trying to copy a database from one server to another. I tried using the following command and it's getting tied up on entering the ssh passwords. If I put in one server's password, it complains about the other and vice versa.

`ssh root@server1 mysqldump --databases db | ssh root@server2 mysql`

I managed to do the transfer by holding the dumps temporarily on my computer, just wondering if there is a way to get this to work.

Answer (score 5):

Use ssh-keygen, copy the .ssh/ file that's generated to the other server, append the contents to the ./.ssh/authorized_keys file, then you can ssh into the other server without any password.

Comment: +1, if you are using key-based authentication, then this should just work.

Comment: Is this the only way or just the easiest? Just curious to know if there's a way to do this without altering the servers' configurations.

Comment: You're not really altering your server's configuration, since it's all a file in your user's home directory. If you don't want to use passwords with SSH this is really the best, quickest, and most painless way to do it.

Comment: Alternatively you could mount the directory (depends on what you have available to do it...NFS, SAMBA, SSHFS) and just copy the file from point A to mountpoint B. That's still an alteration on the way the server works, though.

Comment: Another alternative is scripting with Expect scripts, but you'll end up with passwords being exposed, while logging in with key-based authorization doesn't expose any passwords.

Comment: What kind of box are you running SSH from?  If you are running under X11, you can setup your system so that ssh will run a separate program (ie `ssh-askpass`) to prompt you for credentials.

Comment: More a curiosity than anything. Already got the transfer going. (at)Bart Silverstim Never heard of Expect before. Will check it out. @Zoredache Um, a boring shell window in Ubuntu Unity? Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 3):

Using key authentication is definitely a valid way to go about it and what I'd probably do. If for some reason you can't do that, you can put a named pipe on the intermediate machine instead of storing the file there.

```
mkfifo relaypipe
ssh root@server1 mysqldump --databases db > relaypipe #auth & send to background
ssh root@server2 mysql < relaypipe
```

Comment: Wow.  Great minds, eh...

Comment: That's nifty! Never heard of mkfifo!

Answer (score 3):

If, for some reason, you can't use key authentication and require entering two passwords to complete this, you could use a FIFO:

```
mkfifo myfifo

# In terminal session one, or a screen window, etc.
ssh root@server2 mysql < myfifo

# In terminal session two:
ssh root@server1 mysqldump --databases db > myfifo
```

Comment: +1 since you were obviously writing at the same time as me.

Comment: I think I may have beat you to the punch if I didn't feel obligated to make sure this actually worked the way I thought it would :-)